# Get session variables from Session Provider class in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have a Session Provider class to handle Sessions in my MVC application.

Here is the Session Provider Class...

```
public class SessionProvider
    {
        public static Portal.Application.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.Dtos.User LoggedUser
        {
            get { return (Portal.Application.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.Dtos.User) HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"]; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUser"] = value; }
        }

        public static void Clear()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        }
    }
```

And the User class which used to cast the above Session has these attributes.

- Name
- PhoneNumber

I need to get these Name and Phone number in my View using javascript..

Here what I have dobe so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        User loggedUser = SessionProvider.LoggedUser;     
    }

    var loggedUserName = loggedUser.Name ;
        var loggedUserPhone = loggedUser.PhoneNumber;

</Script>
```

But I have this error in firebug when I run my application..

```
ReferenceError: loggedUser is not defined
var loggedUserName = loggedUser.Name;
```

How can I get those two values? 
I am using Razor View engine...

Comment: you have to use `@Html.Raw` and escape quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        User loggedUser = SessionProvider.LoggedUser;     
    }

    var loggedUserName = "@loggedUser.Name" ;
        var loggedUserPhone = "@loggedUser.PhoneNumber";

</Script>
```

The code you wrote will try to access the Server side object in Javascript which is not at all possible. Your client script doesn't have any idea about your server side declared variables hence it will throw an error. Hence you have to print the property value with the help of razor and use that as string in your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        User loggedUser = SessionProvider.LoggedUser;     
    }
    var loggedUserName = "@(loggedUser.Name)" ;
    var loggedUserPhone = "@(loggedUser.PhoneNumber)";
</Script>
```

Following post will help you to understand the correct syntax.

[Razor’s @: and <text> syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it `@:` escapes razor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    User loggedUser = SessionProvider.LoggedUser;
  @:var loggedUserName = loggedUser.Name;
  @:var loggedUserPhone = loggedUser.PhoneNumber;
}
</Script>
```

However you could read your cookies via JS.

```
var the_cookie = document.cookie;
```